# Set application network connection timeout on Java 11

Tags: networking, timeout, java-11

In Java 8 the following properties existed to allow setting a timeout for all the connections of the application:

```
sun.net.client.defaultConnectTimeout
sun.net.client.defaultReadTimeout
```

This is clearly documented on: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/net/properties.html

In Java 11 these properties are gone https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/net/doc-files/net-properties.html probably for a good reason, but I was wondering if there's still a way of doing this.

Comment: Both properties are [still present in Java11](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/sun/net/NetworkClient.java#L74-L75) it seems they are just not documented anymore.

Comment: It's true actually, thanks! The reason why I though they were missing is cause I was trying to fetch them using `System.getProperty("sun.net.client.defaultConnectTimeout")` instead of `Integer.getInteger("sun.net.client.defaultReadTimeout", 0)`